Is the film still useable if the back of an analog camera opens while you're still on 0 shots and have just loaded in the film?
I just bought an analog camera 35mm ( see website: https://www.hema.nl/vrije-tijd-kantoor/instax/instax-cameras/analoge-fotocamera-35mm-60390006.html ) and I bought the Kodak Gold 200 iso 36exp 3-PAK film rolls.
While loading the camera roll the back of the camera opened (although before the counter went to 1). After closing it I took a picture which made the counter go to number 1 and afterwards I haven't opened it anymore. Can I still use the camera roll or has it become useless? From what I read online I can still use the remaining photos on the camera roll, but some reassurance with this specific camera would be very nice :)

I would like to understand your thought process... why do you think the film might now be useless? Do you know what a roll of film looks like? (I mean, when removed from the cassette.) Perhaps not.

See also: Are my pictures ruined if I opened the camera back with film inside? | Can I still use film after the film door accidentally opened? | Accidentally opened back of analogue camera while rewinding film, are all pictures lost? | Opening back of my film camera | Did I ruin my film when I opened my Canon Sure-shot telemax film camera?

Also this question which actually shows a length of film, which might be useful in terms of visualisation as much as anything: Exposed unshot film roll

You should be fine. Just take into account that the first shot or two are empty, as they are exposed while loading the film. There are tricks such as loading the camera inside a bag that will allow you to get more exposures from the film.
Most film cameras keep unexposed film inside the canister. As you shoot, the film winds on the take-up spool. If you open such a camera, the unexposed film that is still in the canister will be fine, but the already exposed part will be ruined. Judging from the YouTube videos on loading the film into the Agfa Photo Camera, this is your case. Because you didn't shoot anything before, the film was still protected inside the canister.
However, there are some cameras (e.g. Nikon F75) that rewind the whole film on the take-up spool immediately after loading. As you shoot the film, the camera rewinds back onto the canister. In these cameras, opening the back door creates the opposite situation: the exposed part will be safely inside the canister, and the unexposed film will be ruined.

I would add this tip: As it's likely that part of the film still in the canister was exposed, so make one or two "dummy shots" (unimportant things) before you take an important shot. That adds some "safety distance" between the overexposed part and the properly exposed part of the film. Another thing to watch out is that for some cameras the counter resets to zero when the back cover is opened.

Unless your camera has a motor drive you are probably fine.  Some of those cameras unroll all of the film at the start so the taken photos are in the canister and safe if the back is opened.  Manually wound cameras tend to have the unexposed film in the canister so you only lose a few frames if you open the camera at the start instead of all of them.

There is always a very simple answer to this question... Film that is exposed to light is ruined. Film that is concealed within the cassette is protected from light. So you can make your own determination as to what film has been ruined and what is still usable.
